# Should I use scipy.signal.firwin for amplification?

Tags: scipy, signal-processing

Scipy's firwin2 function accepts gain values > 1.0 which leads to an amplification of the corresponding frequency. I have tested this and it seems to work as expected. However, all examples I found online only used gain values between 0.0 and 1.0. This made me wonder: is it a bad idea to make and amplifying filter with the firwin2 function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bad idea at all!  Like other window-based designs, you'll want to make sure that your numtaps (aka the order of the filter) is sufficient to represent your desired frequency response.

The pseudo-standard you're seeing of gain=[0,1] is because, in most cases, over-unity amplification is not considered to improve the signal-to-noise ratio relative to leaving it alone (on the contrary, amplification may introduce clipping).  To improve the signal-to-noise and signal-to-interference ratios, you get rid of the noise or interference.  If the noise and interference are at different frequencies than the signal you desire, you can attenuate them by filtering them.  In this case, the frequency of your signal would keep a gain of 1.0 and the parts you don't want would have a gain of 0.0.

However, there *are* times when you'd want to amplify some frequencies while leaving other frequencies alone or attenuating them.  An example of this is an audio equalizer.  Let's say you had a computer-based audio equalizer.  A user would see an array of sliders for different frequencies and adjust them up or down as they wished.  You might have one of these in your car.  You could easily use firwin2 to create the corresponding FIR coefficients, by simply passing in a frequency vector and a corresponding gain vector.  If a user turns up the bass while leaving all the other frequencies at 0 dB (i.e. unity gain), you would have a gain at the bass frequency you design and 1.0 at all other frequencies.

---

Here's an example of using gains for an audio equalizer.  I found this image for the [Equalizer extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/equalizer/pnbbfmfcemmgekginckbkcndkdiiancm):

[image]

To implement this with firwin2, I can use the following script:

```python
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

Fs = 44100
order = 4096+1
freqs = [0, 32, 64, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, Fs/2]
gains_dB = [4.0, 4.0, 2.3, 1.0, 0.3, -0.3, -1.2, 0.1, 1.6, 3.1, 3.3, 3.3]
gains = 10.**(np.asarray(gains_dB)/10.)
h = signal.firwin2(order, freqs, gains, fs=Fs)

plt.semilogx(np.fft.rfftfreq(len(h))*Fs, 10*np.log10(abs(np.fft.rfft(h))))
plt.title('Equalizer Example')
plt.xlabel('Frequency, Hz')
plt.ylabel('Filter Magnitude Response, dB')
plt.grid(True,which='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]

A few notes:

- You generally plot filters on a semilog graph, because rolloff occurs per octave.
- You generally plot gain in terms of decibels.
- `firwin2` accepts gain in linear units, not decibels, so a conversion was necessary.
- `firwin2` requires frequency representation at 0 and Fs/2, so I added those in and made them equal to their neighbors.

Comment: Great, thank you! Equalization is exactly the scenario I was thinking about :)

Answer (score 1):

The [firwin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html) does not accept a gain factor, only numtaps and

```
firwin(numtaps, cutoff, width=None, window='hamming', pass_zero=True,
           scale=True, nyq=None, fs=None)
```

Either I understood your question incorrectly or you are confusing `cutoff` with gain.
The cutoff indicates the [cutoff freqeuncy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency).

If you want to apply a gain you multiply the returned filter by your gain.

```
from scipy import signal
numtaps = 3
f = 0.1
gain = 5;
h = gain * signal.firwin(numtaps, f)
```

You could plot the response of your filters as follows

```
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

h1 = signal.firwin(256, 0.1)
h2 = signal.firwin(256, 0.3)

plt.plot(np.fft.rfftfreq(len(h1)), abs(np.fft.rfft(h1)))
plt.plot(np.fft.rfftfreq(len(h2)), abs(np.fft.rfft(h2)))
plt.xlabel('F / Fs')
plt.ylabel('Filter gain')
```

[image: filter response]

**EDIT: The question about firwin2**

The function [firwin2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html)(freq, gain) returns a filter that is a constructed as by an interpolation in the frequency domain, followed by a window (scalar multiplication). This operation is linear on the gain array. i.e. `firwin2(freq, A*gain) = A*firwin2(freq, gain)`. So there is restriction like `gain < 1`.

You can confirm this with

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
taps1 = signal.firwin2(150, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]) * 2
taps2 = signal.firwin2(150, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 0.0])
assert(np.allclose(taps1, taps2))
```

Comment: The question is about [`firwin2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html).

Comment: I wrongly wrote firwin in the title but I am talking about firwin2, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The `firwin2` depends linearly in the gain. `firwin(freq, gain*A) = A*firwin(freq, gain)` So you can synthesize a filter with any gain.